# How can I know fire a click event in iframe's parent node if an iframe was clicked

Tags: jquery, iframe

I am having an iframe for google map. I am trying to fire a click event on its parent div if the iframe is being clicked.

I tried somethings like this

```
var maps = $('.map-frame');
$.each(maps, function(){
if (this.contents().find('#map-canvas').has(e.target).length > 0){
do_some_thing();
}
});
```

There is nothing happens in my code. Any idea about that?

Answer (score 0):

```
maybe this does the trick

var maps = $('.map-frame');
$.each(maps, function(){
  $(this).contents().contents().click(function(){
     do_some_thing();
  }};
});
```

but you should better take look at google maps api docs how to trigger a click on the map

something like

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'click')
```

Answer (score 0):

does this not work? you just want to know that a click occurred right? nothing about it?

```
$('.map-frame').click(function (){
  do_something();
});
```